# The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I needed `Msforeach_table` `stored procedure` which depends upon `sys.MSforeach_worker` (System) stored procedure.
I am following [this](https://gist.github.com/metaskills/893599#file-gistfile1-sql) source code to create stored procedure `MSforeach_worker`

The syntax here is for `dbo` and not for `sys` so I have changed it to `sys.MSforeach_worker` from `dbo.MSforeach_worker`
When I try to create in my Databases, i get this error

> The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not
>   have permission to use it

And when I try to create it in `master` db, I get

> CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'

I am confused where should I run this script to create System stored procedure in my `SQL server`.

I have googled but could not find solution to my problem.

Comment: That's not an article, that's the source codes for a procedure.

Answer (score 3):

First, don't use undocumented system `stored procedures`. These are not supported.

Second, if these undocumented procs don't already exist, you must be using `Azure SQL Database`. Azure SQL Database has a significantly different architecture with regards to separation of `master` and user `databases`. Rather than trying to port the procs, I suggest you create your own proc with the functionality you need. Below is an example.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_ForEachTable
    @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
AS
DECLARE 
      @SQLBatch nvarchar(MAX)
    , @TableName nvarchar(261);
DECLARE tables CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0;
OPEN tables;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables INTO @TableName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    SET @SQLBatch = REPLACE(@SQL, N'?', @TableName);
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLBatch;
END;
CLOSE tables;
DEALLOCATE tables;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan, Yes I am using Azure Sql Database with my Laravel Application. I am running command "php artisan db:seed" for data seeding. I will create custom proc for data seeding and then try to make command use my custom proc. Maybe that will work for me.